# Create valid .mp3 file with python

Tags: python, perl, tags, mp3, id3

I saw this piece of perl code, which creates an MP3 object and writes some tags to it. I don't write code in perl but i assume it creates a valid mp3 file with tags.

```
$mp3 = MP3::Tag->new('1.mp3');
$mp3->title_set('Some_title');
$mp3->artist_set('Some_artist');
$mp3->update_tags();  
$mp3->close();
```

I want to write something similar in python.
I've tried mutagen and eyeD3 so far, but i was only able to overwrite tags of an existing mp3 file, with this piece of code, i found somewhere:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

# works with valid mp3 files, which already have tags
def manipulate_id3_tags(path, title, artist, genre):
    try:
        meta = EasyID3(path) # HERE I GET ERROR
        # i assume, if no meta tags where found, it will create some
        # but it never hits the exception even it is ID3NoHeaderError
    except ID3NoHeaderError:                          
        meta = mutagen.File(path, easy=True)    # this also can't be a proper function call
        meta.add_tags()
    meta['title'] = title
    meta['artist'] = artist
    meta['genre'] = genre
    meta.save()
    print(meta)
```

I don't think these modules can create mp3 files from scratch.

I read the [wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Spezifikation) about MP3. My idea was to create a .mp3 file in python and write the header to it. Then i filled the rest with junk code.

This is my sample header according to wikipedia article:
11111111 11111011 11010110 00000100

```
byte_header = b"\xff\xfb\xd6\x04"
mp3 = open(path + "\\my_file.mp3", "wb")
mp3.write(byte_header)
mp3.write(b"\x01" * 800)
mp3.close
```

I get an error at the above commented line
*'C:\Users\Admin\Music\my_file.mp3' doesn't start with an ID3 tag*

Even if the error handling would work, i don't think this method will work.
Can anybody help me out here. Just want to create a simple mp3 dummy file, which i can write valid and readable tags to it.

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrect about Perl's [MP3::Tag](https://metacpan.org/pod/MP3::Tag) module. Its constructor expects an existing valid MP3 file, whose tags you may read and modify. It will not create an MP3 file from scratch

[This site](http://www.xamuel.com/blank-mp3s/) has silent MP3 files with lengths of 1/10 second upwards, and I suggest that you simply download one of those

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Regarding to this page it's not as easy as i thought to create a valid mp3 file by simply writing a valid mp3 header to a file. Expect from the not working error handling, i can write some tags to these silent mp3 files, which e.g. VLC recognizes.

Comment: As the link to blank mp3 is dead, I would suggest using this Github repository instead: [anars/blank-audio](https://github.com/anars/blank-audio).